# Solutions to $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Recently, I remembered the beautiful chain rule from differential geometry, i.e. $D_p(g\circ f)=D_{f(p)}g\circ D_pf$ for maps $M\overset f\to N\overset g\to P$ on manifolds $M,N,P$. If we ignore the points at which we differentiate, the chain rule looks like this: $(g\circ f)_*=g_*\circ f_*$. And that made me curious about whether there are maps $I\overset f\to J\overset g\to\mathbb R$ on intervals $I,J\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$.

More precisely, If we fix a continuously differentiable map $f\colon I\to J$ **or** $g\colon J\to\mathbb R$, how do non-constant and differentiable solutions to the equation $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$ look like (if there are any in the first place)?

It seems impossible to transform the equation $$g'\circ f'\overset!=(g\circ f)'=(g'\circ f)\cdot f'$$ into something useful. I found solutions to the similar problems $(fg)'=f'g'$ and $(f/g)'=f'/g'$, but they didn't provide me with any insight. And solving $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$ for simple examples (see below) also didn't provide me the insight I hoped for.

Which classes of functions $f$ or $g$ (besides those listed below) satisfy $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$? How would I go about solving this problem systematically for arbitrary $f$ or $g$?

Examples:
$$
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        (f,g)\text{ is a solution} & \Rightarrow &
        (f,ag+c)\text{ is a solution for all }a,c\in\mathbb R
        \\
        (f,g_1),(f,g_2)\text{ are solutions} & \Rightarrow &
        (f,g_1+g_2)\text{ is a solution}
        \\
        f(x)=ax+c_1 & \Rightarrow &
        \begin{cases}
            g(x)=bx+c_2\text{ on }f(I)\subseteq J, & \text{if }a=1, \\
            \text{only constant solutions},      & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
        \\
        f(x)=e^x & \Rightarrow &
        \text{only constant solutions}
        \\
        g(x)=x^a,a\neq2 & \Rightarrow &
        \displaystyle f(x)=\Bigl(\frac x{2-a}+c\Bigr)^{2-a}
        \\
        g(x)=x^2+ax & \Rightarrow &
        \displaystyle f(x)=\pm\sqrt{ax+c}-\frac a2+1
        \\
        g(x)=\ln x & \Rightarrow &
        \displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^2}4
    \end{array}
$$

Comment: I fail to understand why the "beautiful" chain rule from differential geometry is different from the one for "conventional" derivatives?

Comment: It seems like you're misunderstanding the first identity. The composition $D_{f(p)}g \circ D_p f$ is a composition of linear maps on differentials. If you translate that into one dimension, the composition is multiplication, and $D_{f(p)}g = g'(f(p)), D_p f = f'(p)$ so you get the usual chain rule $g'\circ f(p) * f'(p)$.

Comment: @Fabian As a formula the chain rule from differential geoemtry looks like $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$. And now I am wondering how the solutions of $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$ look like.

Comment: @TokenToucan I know that, but if you omit the point at which you differentiate, then the chain rule looks like $(g\circ f)_*=g_*\circ f_*$. I didn't mean to justify finding solutions with the chain rule from differential geometry, it just got me curious whether or not $(g\circ f)'=g'\circ f'$ actually has solutions.

Comment: There are solutions if $g=\ln$; in that case solve $f'/f=1/f'$.

Comment: Also if $g$ is the square root.

Comment: Or $g$ is any power function.